# Administrative Password saving and reseting in asp.net application

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, sql, c#-3.0

What is the best approach for saving Super Administrator / Administrator password in an application. 
Super Admin is also a client user, so not sure, how techy he could be, for that i am thinking about some good approach to save admin password, that could be in db or in web.config, and what if super admin forgets his password, then how can he reset it? any idea which approach or in which direction should i go forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may provide a command to client for making a super admin in README which he can copy and paste in terminal and run. It would make a super user. Then he can change his password may be using the command or GUI.